# Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting

Tags: android

Does anybody have any insight about why I'm getting this warning in LogCat?

> 01-18 01:18:17.475: W/HardwareRenderer(25992): Attempting to
>   initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting

I do this with my WebView in my Main activity (the main thread):

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_webview);
wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

and I have this in my manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".Main"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
```

Comment: "outside of main thread" sounds suspicious; are *any* threads being (manually) created?

Comment: Yes, but none have anything to do with hardware acceleration. There is some Facebook dialog code (not even called before I see this warning) and a GCM service.

Comment: take a traceview and check which thread called  enableHardwareAcceleration , by knowing the thread name you might get some clues

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the Hardware Acceleration works in Android:

```
private void enableHardwareAcceleration(WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs) {
    mAttachInfo.mHardwareAccelerated = false;
    mAttachInfo.mHardwareAccelerationRequested = false;

    // Don't enable hardware acceleration when the application is in compatibility mode
    if (mTranslator != null) return;

    // Try to enable hardware acceleration if requested
    final boolean hardwareAccelerated = 
            (attrs.flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED) != 0;

    if (hardwareAccelerated) {
        if (!HardwareRenderer.isAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        // Persistent processes (including the system) should not do
        // accelerated rendering on low-end devices.  In that case,
        // sRendererDisabled will be set.  In addition, the system process
        // itself should never do accelerated rendering.  In that case, both
        // sRendererDisabled and sSystemRendererDisabled are set.  When
        // sSystemRendererDisabled is set, PRIVATE_FLAG_FORCE_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
        // can be used by code on the system process to escape that and enable
        // HW accelerated drawing.  (This is basically for the lock screen.)

        final boolean fakeHwAccelerated = (attrs.privateFlags &
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_FAKE_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED) != 0;
        final boolean forceHwAccelerated = (attrs.privateFlags &
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_FORCE_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED) != 0;

        if (!HardwareRenderer.sRendererDisabled || (HardwareRenderer.sSystemRendererDisabled
                && forceHwAccelerated)) {
            // Don't enable hardware acceleration when we're not on the main thread
            if (!HardwareRenderer.sSystemRendererDisabled
                    && Looper.getMainLooper() != Looper.myLooper()) {
                Log.w(HardwareRenderer.LOG_TAG, "Attempting to initialize hardware "
                        + "acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting");
                return;
            }

            final boolean translucent = attrs.format != PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
            if (mAttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer != null) {
                mAttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.destroy(true);
            }                
            mAttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer = HardwareRenderer.createGlRenderer(2, translucent);
            mAttachInfo.mHardwareAccelerated = mAttachInfo.mHardwareAccelerationRequested
                    = mAttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer != null;
        } else if (fakeHwAccelerated) {
            // The window had wanted to use hardware acceleration, but this
            // is not allowed in its process.  By setting this flag, it can
            // still render as if it was accelerated.  This is basically for
            // the preview windows the window manager shows for launching
            // applications, so they will look more like the app being launched.
            mAttachInfo.mHardwareAccelerationRequested = true;
        }
    }
}
```

From there, you can see that the log you are getting is when the hardware acceleration is asked outside of the main thread (as the log says).

In your case, you have to get more deep in your code and see all the non main threads, which one is calling the hardware acceleration.

I can't help you without more details (some code etc).

Comment: The webview is the only other thread. I need to make sure that it gets hardware accelerated.

Comment: Try to use breackpoints in order to see when your exception is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As Per documentation

> setRenderPriority

should only be called once per process.

> Sets the priority of the Render thread. Unlike the other settings,
>   this one only needs to be called once per process. The default value
>   is NORMAL.

Possible soultion to your problem

- Would be removal of the websetting.setRenderPriority.
- Would  another thread that you have not shared in the above code would be accessing
  the hardware

Comment: It seems removing the setRenderPriority() would remove the warning, but since the majority of the app's processing takes place in the webview, I do want to make sure that it's render priority is high.

Answer (score -1):

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams dfparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 0);
    webview.setLayoutParams(dfparams);
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("url", content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
            webview.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is just some (random?) code, not an answer to the question.